# Change the color of table when even or odd

Tags: php, html, css

I have this lines of code (php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> okay</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "<table border=2>";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++ ) {  
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td >".$i."</td>";
    for ( $j = 2; $j <= 10; $j++ ) {
        echo "<td>".$i * $j."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the background color of even numbers to change to green (with white font) and the odd numbers to red (with black font).
How can I do this ?

Comment: Do what? Set background? Check even/odd?

Comment: Use CSS for that, `tr:nth-of-type(odd) { /* Your CSS rule */ }`

Comment: I want the odd and even numbers not the odd or even rows 
ex: 2 must be green background and white font 
     4 must be green background and white font 
     5 must be red background and black font

Answer (score 1):

Use `%` operator of php to determine odd/even row

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> okay</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "<table border=2 >";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++ ) {  
  $style="background:red;color:black";
  if($i%2==0)      
    $style="background:green;color:white";
echo "<tr style=$style>";
echo "<td >".$i."</td>";
for ( $j = 2; $j <= 10; $j++ ) {
echo "<td>".$i * $j."</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Or simply by css:

```
tr:nth-of-type(odd)
{
    background:red;color:black;
}
tr:nth-of-type(even)
{
    background:green;color:white;
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to change color when value is odd/even. try below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> okay</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "<table border=2 >";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++ ) {    
echo "<tr >";
$style="background:red;color:black";
  if($i%2==0)      
    $style="background:green;color:white";
echo "<td style=$style>".$i."</td>";
for ( $j = 2; $j <= 10; $j++ ) {
  $val = ($i * $j);
  $style="background:red;color:black";
  if($val%2==0)      
    $style="background:green;color:white";
  echo "<td style=$style>".$val."</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would argue that using CSS is better for this than doing it through PHP though.

Comment: It is not right ... 
it just shows every row with different color (first row  red color, second row green color , third row red color , forth row green color etc.. ) so it just changes colors every row . What i need is : 
Even number = green color
Odd number = red color 
 
What i need is that every odd number is

Comment: so you need to change color when value is odd / even?

Answer (score 0):

i have added if partto check odd or even the print with respect to your chioce

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> okay</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "<table border=2>";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++ ) {  
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td >".$i."</td>";
    for ( $j = 2; $j <= 10; $j++ ) {
        if(($i*$j)%2==0)
           echo "<td style="color:white;background-color:green">".$i * $j."</td>";
       else
            echo "<td style="color:black;background-color:red">".$i * $j."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
 <?php
if ($i % 2 != "0") # An odd row
  $rowColor = "green";
else # An even row
  $rowColor = "orange"; 
?>
```